# Supabase query with multiple foreign table queries (!inner) not returning any rows

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

So I am querying a profile table that has fk relations to 'recommendations' and 'playlist'. I want to get the profile info, recommendations of a certain type, and playlist entries marked active.

However, unless there are items that that fulfill both queries, the query will return zero rows. If  there are recommendations of type 'rock', but no active playlist entries then I get zero rows.

What I want returned:

```json
[{
name: 'Joe',
email: 'joe@example.com',
recommendations: [{id: 1, title: 'some title', ...}, {id: 2, title: 'other title', ...}],
playlist:[]
}]
```

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('profile')
 .select('''
    name,
    email,
    recommendations!inner(
        id,
        title,
        url,
        date,
        type
    ),
    playlist!inner(
      id,
      active,
      played,
      played_date
    )
    '''
    )
    .eq('playlist.active', true)
    .eq('recommendations.type', 'rock')
```

I looked at 'or' queries, but these are for queries filtering the same table.

Answer (score 0):

`or` across related tables work on [postgREST latest prelease](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/releases/tag/v10.1.1.20221215), which is available on the [supabase CLI](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/introduction). Try it like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('profile')
 .select('''
    name,
    email,
    recommendations(
        id,
        title,
        url,
        date,
        type
    ),
    playlist(
      id,
      active,
      played,
      played_date
    )
    '''
    )
    .eq('playlist.active', true)
    .eq('recommendations.type', 'rock')
    .or('(playlist.not.is.null, recommendations.not.is.null)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Search will be done on the relative table column by adding the inner joining !inner on relative tables

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('profile')
 .select('''
    name,
    email,
    recommendations!inner(
        id,
        title,
        url,
        date,
        type
    ),
    playlist!inner(
      id,
      active,
      played,
      played_date
    )
    '''
    )
    .eq('playlist.active', true)
    .eq('recommendations.type', 'rock')
    .or('(playlist.not.is.null, recommendations.not.is.null)')
```